# Finding if a Student meets a condition in a given range of years

Tags: sql

I have the following table called `df`, all dates are DATE format and look like `2010-01-01 00:00:00`:

| student | var1 | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2010-01-01 | 2013-01-01 |
| 1 | b | 2010-01-01 | 2013-01-01 |
| 1 | b | 2013-05-05 | 2015-09-09 |
| 1 | a | 2017-10-10 | 2018-09-01 |
| 2 | c | 2010-01-01 | 2014-01-01 |
| 2 | a | 2015-01-01 | 2017-09-01 |
| 2 | b | 2019-01-01 | 2023-03-05 |

**My Question:**

- Consider years from 2010 to 2020
- For each student, between March 1st-March 1st of each year, I want to find out if the student had at least one value of var1 = a
- If yes, then TRUE else FALSE
  Note: when a student has missing information in a given set of years, still FALSE

The final results look like this:

| SN | Student | start_time | end_time | at_least_one_var1_a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2010-03-01 | 2011-03-01 | TRUE |
| 2 | 1 | 2011-03-01 | 2012-03-01 | TRUE |
| 3 | 1 | 2012-03-01 | 2013-03-01 | TRUE |
| 4 | 1 | 2013-03-01 | 2014-03-01 | FALSE |
| 5 | 1 | 2014-03-01 | 2015-03-01 | FALSE |
| 6 | 1 | 2015-03-01 | 2016-03-01 | FALSE |
| 7 | 1 | 2016-03-01 | 2017-03-01 | FALSE |
| 8 | 1 | 2017-03-01 | 2018-03-01 | TRUE |
| 9 | 1 | 2018-03-01 | 2019-03-01 | TRUE |
| 10 | 1 | 2019-03-01 | 2020-03-01 | FALSE |
| 11 | 2 | 2010-03-01 | 2011-03-01 | FALSE |
| 12 | 2 | 2011-03-01 | 2012-03-01 | FALSE |
| 13 | 2 | 2012-03-01 | 2013-03-01 | FALSE |
| 14 | 2 | 2013-03-01 | 2014-03-01 | FALSE |
| 15 | 2 | 2014-03-01 | 2015-03-01 | TRUE |
| 16 | 2 | 2015-03-01 | 2016-03-01 | TRUE |
| 17 | 2 | 2016-03-01 | 2017-03-01 | TRUE |
| 18 | 2 | 2017-03-01 | 2018-03-01 | TRUE |
| 19 | 2 | 2018-03-01 | 2019-03-01 | FALSE |
| 20 | 2 | 2019-03-01 | 2020-03-01 | FALSE |

**My Problem:** I am not sure how to do this in SQL

I tried to this with the following logic:

Step1: Create a CTE with all date ranges

```
WITH step1 AS (
  SELECT '2010-03-01' AS start_date, '2011-03-01' AS end_date UNION ALL
  SELECT '2011-03-01', '2012-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2012-03-01', '2013-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2013-03-01', '2014-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2014-03-01', '2015-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2015-03-01', '2016-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2016-03-01', '2017-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-03-01', '2018-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-03-01', '2019-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-03-01', '2020-03-01'
)
```

Step 2: Write a "sandwich" style join to see check students relative to start_date and end_dates:

```
joined_data AS (
  SELECT 
    t.student,
    d.start_date,
    d.end_date,
    t.var1
  FROM 
    df t
  JOIN 
    date_ranges d
  ON 
    t.start <= d.end_date AND t.end >= d.start_date
)
```

**However STEP 2 is returning an empty result**

Had Step 2 worked, I could have then used a series of CASE WHEN statement to perform the rest of the counts

```
var1_counts AS (
  SELECT 
    student,
    start_date,
    end_date,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN var1 = 'a' THEN 1 END) AS var1_count
  FROM 
    joined_data
  GROUP BY 
    student, start_date, end_date
)
SELECT 
  student,
  start_date,
  end_date,
  CASE WHEN var1_count > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS at_least_one_var1_a
FROM 
  var1_counts;
```

**Can someone please show me what I can do this fix this problem?** I am trying to do this without cross joins, correlated queries or recursive queries (I usually use techniques like JOIN 1=1 to deal with these situations).

**Note:** Currently I am looking into using TO_CHAR(), TO_DATE(), CAST() and DATE_PART() and DATE_TRUNC() functions to see if this can be useful?

Comment: does netezza support date time manipulation function? something like [tsql YEAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: Based on the result you’ve provided, did you mean “Consider years from 2010 to 2020”, not 2000?

Comment: @bagustesa: thank you so much for your reply! Since there is  only a small range of dates, I was hoping to manually accomplish this using the first cte?

Comment: @NickW: thank you so much for your reply! I have now made this correction!

Comment: i also curious why step 2 turns up empty. i [tried on sql server](https://dbfiddle.uk/gIA6o5Xl) and it work just fine. perhaps there is something else unsupported by [tag:netezza} in the sql standard.

Comment: I tried using the CAST function i.e. CAST(start as date) .. but still nothing. I wonder if there is some way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than changing your column names (`END` is a reserved identifier), the SQL works fine on Netezza.

```
nzsql <<eof
    create table df (student integer, var1 varchar(10), start_date date, end_date date);
eof

nzload -t df -delim " " <<eof
1 a 2010-01-01 2013-01-01
1 b 2010-01-01 2013-01-01
1 b 2013-05-05 2015-09-09
1 a 2017-10-10 2018-09-01
2 c 2010-01-01 2014-01-01
2 a 2015-01-01 2017-09-01
2 b 2019-01-01 2023-03-05
eof

#########################################################

nzsql <<eof

WITH date_ranges AS (
  SELECT '2010-03-01' AS start_date, '2011-03-01' AS end_date UNION ALL
  SELECT '2011-03-01', '2012-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2012-03-01', '2013-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2013-03-01', '2014-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2014-03-01', '2015-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2015-03-01', '2016-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2016-03-01', '2017-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-03-01', '2018-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-03-01', '2019-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-03-01', '2020-03-01'
),

joined_data AS (
  SELECT
    t.student,
    d.start_date,
    d.end_date,
    t.var1
  FROM
   df t
  JOIN
    date_ranges d
  ON
    t.start_DATE <= d.end_date AND t.end_DATE >= d.start_date
),

var1_counts AS (
  SELECT
    student,
    start_date,
    end_date,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN var1 = 'a' THEN 1 END) AS var1_count
  FROM
    joined_data
  GROUP BY
    student, start_date, end_date
)

SELECT
  student,
  start_date,
  end_date,
  CASE WHEN var1_count > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS at_least_one_var1_a
FROM
  var1_counts;

eof
```

Comment: It is giving 18 rows. How come its is the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Using your original code we don't get your "expected results" (just 18 rows instead of 20 ... a couple of years don't show up).

Here is a rewrite

- Just one CTE (instead of many/nested CTEs)
- And that CTE is used to create the date_ranges (which can much more easily expand from 10 to  years if one wants)
- It does use a CROSS JOIN (which is supported)
- And the result set incudes all 20 rows

```
WITH date_ranges AS (
  select ('2010-03-01'::date + interval '1 year' * idx)::date as start_date,
         (start_date + interval '1 year')::date               as end_date
  from _v_vector_idx where start_date between '2010-03-01' and '2019-03-01'
)

SELECT
    t.student,
    d.start_date,
    d.end_date,
    NVL2(max(case when  t.start_DATE <= d.end_date AND t.end_DATE >= d.start_date and t.var1 = 'a' then 1 else null end),'TRUE','FALSE')
FROM
    df t
    CROSS JOIN date_ranges d

group by 1,2,3
order by 1,2,3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Explanation first:

- The result consists of *m* years x *n* distinct students so use `cross join` and `distinct`
- Use [date range overlap query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap) to find overlapping rows
- Use `exists` instead of left join because...
  With left join, one March-to-March range could overlap two rows from actual table so you could get more rows than expected, exists doesn't duplicate

The query:

```
with yearlist as (
    select '2010-03-01' as start_date, '2011-03-01' as end_date union all
    select '2011-03-01', '2012-03-01' union all
    select '2012-03-01', '2013-03-01' union all
    select '2013-03-01', '2014-03-01' union all
    select '2014-03-01', '2015-03-01' union all
    select '2015-03-01', '2016-03-01' union all
    select '2016-03-01', '2017-03-01' union all
    select '2017-03-01', '2018-03-01' union all
    select '2018-03-01', '2019-03-01' union all
    select '2019-03-01', '2020-03-01'
), studentlist as (
    select distinct student
    from df
)
select
    studentlist.student,
    yearlist.start_date,
    yearlist.end_date,
    case when exists (
        select *
        from df
        where df.var1 = 'a'
        and df.student = studentlist.student
        and df.end > yearlist.start_date
        and df.start < yearlist.end_date
    ) then 'true' else 'false' end as has_a
from yearlist
cross join studentlist
order by studentlist.student, yearlist.start_date
```

[Demo on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/H_O8roih)

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to correctly join the date ranges from your CTE with the df table such that for each student and each year range, we check if there's at least one record with var1 = 'a'.

Here's a revised version of your SQL query:

```
    -- Step 1: Create a CTE with all date ranges
WITH date_ranges AS (
  SELECT '2010-03-01'::DATE AS start_date, '2011-03-01'::DATE AS end_date UNION ALL
  SELECT '2011-03-01'::DATE, '2012-03-01'::DATE UNION ALL
  SELECT '2012-03-01'::DATE, '2013-03-01'::DATE UNION ALL
  SELECT '2013-03-01'::DATE, '2014-03-01'::DATE UNION ALL
  SELECT '2014-03-01'::DATE, '2015-03-01'::DATE UNION ALL
  SELECT '2015-03-01'::DATE, '2016-03-01'::DATE UNION ALL
  SELECT '2016-03-01'::DATE, '2017-03-01'::DATE UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-03-01'::DATE, '2018-03-01'::DATE UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-03-01'::DATE, '2019-03-01'::DATE UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-03-01'::DATE, '2020-03-01'::DATE
),

-- Step 2: Join the date ranges with the df table
joined_data AS (
  SELECT 
    d.start_date,
    d.end_date,
    t.student,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.var1 = 'a' AND t.start <= d.end_date AND t.end >= d.start_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has_var1_a
  FROM 
    date_ranges d
  CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT student FROM df) s
  LEFT JOIN 
    df t ON t.student = s.student
  GROUP BY 
    d.start_date, d.end_date, t.student
)

-- Final selection
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY student, start_date) AS SN,
  student,
  start_date,
  end_date,
  CASE WHEN has_var1_a > 0 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS at_least_one_var1_a
FROM 
  joined_data
ORDER BY 
  student, start_date;
```

Key Points:

1. The date_ranges CTE remains the same, defining the year ranges.
2. In joined_data, we use a CROSS JOIN to pair each student with each date range. This ensures that we consider all students for all date ranges.
3. We then perform a LEFT JOIN with the df table to find matching records.
4. The MAX function in combination with the CASE statement is used to determine if there's at least one record with var1 = 'a' for each student in each date range.
5. Finally, we select the required columns, using ROW_NUMBER() to generate the serial number (SN).

This query should give you the desired output, checking for the presence of var1 = 'a' for each student in each specified year range.